# Spring AMQP: Unable to set MessageProperties using RabbitMessagingTemplate

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq, spring-amqp

I have tried this to set expiration time of a message and converting and sending it using RabbitMessagingTemplate:

```
Map<String,Object> headers = new HashMap<>();
headers.put("expiration", "20000");
rabbitMessagingTemplate.convertAndSend(exchange.getName(),routingKey, event, headers);
```

but it does not work because expiration shall be set as a property and NOT as a header. Unfortunately `RabbitMessagingTemplate` does not provide a way to pass message properties but only headers. On the other hand I need to convert the message becasue I use JecksonMessageConverter. 
How can I add message properties before sending the message with RabbitMessagingTemplate?

Answer (score 2):

Add a MessagePostProcessor to the underlying RabbitRemplate's beforePublishPostProcessors.

I  can't look at the code right now but I am surprised it's not mapped.

**EDIT**

Use header name `amqp_expiration`. See `AmqpHeaders.EXPIRATION`. It is mapped to the message property.

Unrecognized headers are mapped to headers.

**EDIT2**

In any case, given your requirements, you might be better off not using the `RabbitMessagingTemplate` but use the `RabbitTemplate` and a `MessagePostProcessor` instead; it will be a little more efficient...

```
rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend(exchange.getName(), routingKey, event, m -> {
    m.getMessageProperties().setExpiration(...);
    ...
    return m;
};
```